# An example of a matrix $B \in Q^{2,2}$ that is diagonalisable in one field but not another

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples, diagonalization

I am trying to find an example of a matrix $B \in Q^{2,2}$ that is diagonalisable if the base field is $R$, but which is not diagonalisable if the base field is $Q$. I am not entirely sure if I am grasping the concepts behind a base field correctly so an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Just pick a matrix that has real but irrational eigenvalues. For example one with characteristic polynomial $x^2-2$-

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, for example.